# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=2.0.0.0

Tags: .net-assembly

I recently updated a website from VS2008 to VS2010. Publish with Web Deploy tool but I get the following error

> Server Error in '/' Application. Parser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. Parser Error Message: Reference.svcmap: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Source Error: [No relevant source lines] Source File: /App_WebReferences/websConsultarCOVE/ Line: 1 Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' could not be loaded. WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]. Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18010

---

The error is in reference to a third party webservices

OS: Windows Server 2012

Thank you very much in advance